# i can't understand what to use in this code(+= or .join())

Tags: python-3.x

so the question asks to return a string in which every character of the original string are 3 times i.e if the word='hello'
then the string should return 'hhheeelllooo'
(python code)

i tried using string.join in this case but it only returns 'hhh' but if i use string+=character*3 it works .so what is the differense and why isn't it working

```
def myfunc (text):
    string=''
    for letter in text:
        return string.join(letter*3)
```

but

```
def myfunc (text):
string=''
for letter in text:
string+=letter*3
return string
```

it works

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code. Why it does or does not work might be related to that.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `return string.join(letter*3)` (even though it's not what you want) it will exit the function without finishing the loop, thus returning the result for only the first letter. Also, `string.join(X)` works with sequences such as lists, and it glues the elements in the list `X` with the string `string`, so if you want to use it you can use it this way:

```
def myfunc(text):
    return ''.join([letter * 3 for letter in text])

print(myfunc('hello'))
```

Output:

```
hhheeellllllooo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for letter in text:
        return string.join(letter*3)  # return at first letter,usel
```

it will work

```
''.join([i*3 for i in text])
```